# Can we have a self-study tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags

There are lots of good questions on CV asking for references for self study, or for methods of learning, or other self study resources (a search for `learning -[machine-learning]` turns up a few).

Many of these questions are highly relevant to someone like me, who has a basic first year uni intro-to-stats course as background, and would very much like to learn more, but is feeling a bit out of their depth. But many of these questions are quite hard to search for, or come at the topic from an angle that might not be immediately apparent, so having a tag to chuck them all under would be incredibly useful.

I would suggest `[self-study]`, but there might be better options, like a more general `[education]`, or just `[study]` (although that's a little cryptic).

(I would tag this question `[tag-request]`, but I don't have the rep)

Comment: I believe it takes very little reputation to create a new tag when you formulate a question.  This causes tags to evolve as the community and the nature of its questions evolve.  It appears that we already have tags for your topic, including [tag:books] and [tag:references].  Are you looking for something other than what those offer?

Comment: I can see potential value in such a tag as a *meta*-tag counterpart to `[homework]`. In particular, if users understand that `[self-study]` means "sounds like a homework question, but it's not really homework" this could be useful and cut down on such commentary to the actual question. Of course, that can be abused, but so can the lack of tagging as `[homework]` in the first place. That said, used in this way, it should *not* be a tag that is used in isolation (i.e., the question should have other tags as well).

Comment: @whuber: 300 rep. Yeah, I'm looking for something that encompases (most of) those, and also talks about methods of learning.  #cardinal: I see "homework" as more about "help me answer my specific question" type questions. I'm looking more for "I'm trying to find my way through the forest of statistics blind, and I keep getting poked with sharp sticks. What tools/strategies can I use to get me out of this predicament?" kind of questions.

Answer (score 2):

It appears we already have [references](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references), [homework](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework), and [books](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books), which would cover the majority of needs of a self-learner. As such, I'm marking this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).